# SqlAlchemy Create Table Specifying Schema

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I want to copy a table from SQL Server to Sqlite via SqlAlchemy reflection.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table

source_engine = create_engine(...) # create sql server engine
source_connection = source_engine.connect()
source_metadata = MetaData() # (1)

destination_engine = create_engine('sqlite:///test.db', echo=True)
destination_connection = destination_engine.connect()

Table('table_name', source_metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=source_engine) # (2)

source_metadata.create_all(destination_engine)
```

The above works with the default schema (dbo) but I want to specify the schema of the reflected tables in SQL Server.

When I change (1) to `source_metadata = Metadata(schema='dbo')` or (2) to `Table(table_name, source_metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=source_engine, schema='dbo')` I get the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unknown database "dbo"
```

I know the issue is with sqlite. When I create a table in SQLite Studio like below, I get the same error:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.table_name(...
```

but the following creates the table successfully:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo.table_name](...
```

Finally, I have tried the below with no success:

`destination_engine.execute("ATTACH DATABASE 'test.db' AS 'dbo'")`

How do I create a table specifying the schema using SqlAlchemy?

Answer (score 3):

First, sqlite does not support schemas as they are known to be in the other RDBMS. And the fact that `[dbo.table_name]` is created for you is just that - it is a full table name including the brackets.

Therefore, I assume you will be OK with just dropping it completely.

And to do that, just set it to `None` before you call `create_all`:

```
# either specifying `schema='xxx'` on the Table() or on `Metadata()` or both will work just fine
source_metadata = MetaData(schema='xxx')
table1 = Table('table_name', source_metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=source_engine, schema='xxx')  

# unset schema
table1.schema = None

# or if you have multiple tables, you will just have to set `.schema = None` to all of them:
for tbl in src_metadata.tables.values():
    tbl.schema = None

# now create the tables on the destination engine
source_metadata.create_all(destination_engine)
```

Alternatively, if you cannot drop the schema, you can just change table names with the prefix:

```
for tbl in src_metadata.tables.values():
    tbl.name = tbl.schema + '_' + tbl.name
    tbl.schema = None
```

And in any event you might need to fix all the ForeignKeys as well... so it is much more work than just changing the schema ;)

---

*And I am afraid the `schema` might not be the last problem whey copying the data from one type DB to another. Incompatible data types will probably follow. If they do, read [Reflecting with Database-Agnostic Types](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/reflection.html#reflecting-with-database-agnostic-types). Also with renaming tables/schemas, you might need to take care of re-linking `ForeignKey`s, `Index`'s etc.*

Answer (score 0):

We can use the Inspector feature available in the SqlAlchemy API to create new tables. The schema, table, and respective constraints are taken care by the "Inspector API"-

```py
from sqlalchemy import inspect,create_engine

engine = create_engine('....')

ins=inspect(engine)
```

Refer the below doc for more info:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/reflection.html?highlight=inspector#fine-grained-reflection-with-inspector